# how to add a file to my project programmatically

Tags: objective-c, file, plist, project, addition

I created a **WinDef.plist** file in the Application Support folder which contains default values.
I would like to add this file to my project without doing it manually.

[image]

Any idea how I could do it?

Ronald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following methods in your application didfinishlaunching method

```
-(void) checkAndCreateFile
    {
        //-------------------------------------------
        BOOL success;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:cFilePath];
        //-------------------------------------------
        //File already there
        if(success)
        {
            return;
        }
        //-------------------------------------------
        //create file
        NSString *filePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:cfileName];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePathFromApp toPath:cfilePath error:nil];

    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Method : copyFile
// Method to create file
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
-(void) copyFile
{

        cfileName = @"WinDef.plist";

    NSArray *documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    cfilePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:cfileName];
    [self checkAndCreateFile];

}
```

This will save WinDef.plist file in your application document folder if you want

And if you want to access that file values then you can retrieve it by using following code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"WinDef" ofType: @"plist"]; 
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];
id obj1 = [dictionary objectForKey: @"YourKey"];
```

This will give you that key value in dictionary

Comment: Oh, I´m sorry. I probably didn´t explain my problem correctly. I want the file to stay where it is. I want it to appear in the Project Navigator in the side bar. I added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: Its OK Ronald.Now I have added code for getting values from your plist file according to key value.This dictionary you can use to get your default setting values

Comment: äh, sorry, thats what I already do :) You see I´m doing some testing on my WindowViewHeaderBar utility. While doing this I got to delete the WinDef from time to time. Right now I´m switching to the finder, delete the file manually and put it back to the Project Navigator after it was created again, also manually. What I want: I want to delete the file from Project Navigator, deleting the file and want that the newly created file (which already works) appears in the Project Navigator. I don´t see how to bring the file to the Project Navigator.

Comment: I found a solution using AppleScript. Thank you for your patience ;)

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question... why is it marked correct? Anyway, I was looking for a way to add files (actually a complete directory structure) to project navigator too. :-)